# Can a GCP service account with owner for a project grant rights to user account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts

I have been given a service account & json file with owner rights to a test project.  Can I grant rights to my gmail.com account from that to be able to manage the project through the normal portal cloud.google.com view?

This seems backwards to me - I would expect a user with rights to that project to have to grant my gmail.com account to that service account.

I'm just starting out so please let me know if I am missing something here.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, a service account can add a Gmail user to a Google Cloud Project. The command is `gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ...`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/add-iam-policy-binding

Comment: The IAM part isn't easy at the beginning, but very powerful and important. Don't hesitate to ask on this ;) And keep in mind that service account key file (JSON) is a secret and don't expose it. You don't need it on Google Cloud product and keep the least privilege principle in mind!!! Courage:*

Comment: John Hanley - that worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason for which a service account exists with owner rights?

A service account is intended to perform a service to service integration with specific rights required for that service account. A big wrapper owner privilege is an anti-pattern in my opinion.

I would recommend you to talk to your admin to provide you ownership on your google account instead (only if you actually need it) and only create service account with least privileges as if your service account credentials are compromised the risk would be very huge.

**Updates:**

Here are the steps but I you need to be careful and should ask your admin if you should be doing this.

First, log into gcloud using your service account (which has owner access),

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account your-service-account@google.com  --key-file=/path/key.json --project=testproject
```

Second, create new user in your project using,

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding my-project \
--member=user:my-user@example.com --role=roles/viewer
```

References:

1. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account
2. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#updating-gcloud

Comment: Yes, this is just a test to see what I can do in that project.  Since I'm new I'm not sure if I can connect that service account to my user account or if I would need them to do that step.

Comment: @Seano'brien I have added the commands to do the same. The create user command will only work if you have sufficient privileges to do so. let me know if it works :)